# What if someone copies my answer to get reputation

Tags: discussion, answers

What if someone copies my answer with little modification for same question to get reputation.

This is for the same question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31383718/2034794) is the question where I answered and another one copied my answer.

Comment: @Gimby: I'm not sure that's a duplicate, because (a) the whole content is copied verbatim, and (b) attribution is provided in that case.

Answer (score 14):

From everything I can see they did not copy your answer.  They are using different example data and then are accessing the data differently.  The fact that both of the answers are posted 5 minutes apart means the answerer could have been working on their answer while you posted yours.

In programming a lot of code is going to end up looking the same even coming from completely disparate sources.  This is even more prevalent in simple examples/answers.  My advice is first assume that nothing bad is going on unless you can find a pattern / habit / proof of wrongdoing.

Comment: Just to add that in a legitimate case of plagiarism, raise a flag for a moderator and explain the situation.